# Euler-Lagrange equations gives trivial solution

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am trying to find the extremals of the functional
$$\mathcal{F}(u) \, := \, \int_0^1 (u(t)^2 - u(t)u'(t)) \, dt $$
where $u \in C^1([0, 1], \mathbb{R}). $

Solving the Euler-Lagrange equations, it seems to me that the only extremals is $u \equiv 0$.

**My attempt:** $\, $ The Lagrangian is
$F(t, y, z) = y^2 - yz$, which gives for the partial derivatives
$\frac{\partial{F}}{{\partial y}} =  2y-z$ and $\frac{\partial{F}}{{\partial z}} = - y$. Then the Euler-Lagrange equation $\frac{\partial{F}}{{\partial y}}(t, u, u') - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial{F}}{{\partial z}}(t, u, u') = 0$ is equivalent to
$$2u(t) - u'(t) - \frac{d}{dt}[- u(t)] =  2u(t) = 0.$$

Am I wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you have zero boundary conditions, this is the only possible candidate. But do we know if a minimizer exists?

Comment: @Meowdog In case $u(0) = 0 = u(1)$, I have to show that the extremal is a minimum, but if I assume only $u(0) = 0$ I have to show that the minimum does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u(0) = u(1) = 0$, then
$$
\int^1_0 u(t)u'(t) ~\mathrm{d}t = u^2(t) \bigg \vert^{t=1}_{t=0} - \int^1_0 u'(t)u(t)~\mathrm{d}t = - \int^1_0 u'(t)u(t)~\mathrm{d}t \iff \int^1_0 u(t)u'(t)~\mathrm{d}t = 0
$$
using integration by parts. So in this case we have
$$
\mathcal{F}(u) = \int^1_0~u^2(t)~\mathrm{d}t.
$$

Now it is obvious that $u \equiv 0$ is the unique minimizer.

If we only assume that $u(0) = 0$, then $u_n(x) := nx$ is admissible for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now
$$
\mathcal{F}(u_n) = -\frac{n^2}{6} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} - \infty,
$$
which proves that $\mathcal{F}$ does not attain its minimum in this case.

The Euler-Lagrange-equation helps you with neither of the two problems because it is a *necessary* and not a sufficient condition.

Comment: Thanks, very clear!